# How to make Multi-Dimensional arrays resized maybe use List(Of List(Of Byte))

Tags: vb.net, list, multidimensional-array

I have this kind of code.
Everytime the method before is called it should resize (ReDim Preserve) the array by 1.. But it's impossible for multi-dimensional arrays due an error you get saying this `'ReDim' can only change the rightmost dimension.`

The suggestion I researched was to use a `List(Of List(Of Byte)`
But I still cannot figure out how do use that seems I'll have to keep creating new List objects everytime, any suggestions would be helpful

```
Dim adjMatrix As Byte(,)
Dim setDimensions As Boolean = False

Public Sub connectNode(ByVal start As Node, ByVal endd As Node)
    'This method will be called to make connect two nodes
    If setDimensions = False Then
        ReDim Preserve adjMatrix(999 - 1, 999)
        setDimensions = True
    End If
    Dim startIndex As Integer = nodes.IndexOf(start)
    Dim endIndex As Integer = nodes.IndexOf(endd)
    adjMatrix(startIndex, endIndex) = 1
    adjMatrix(endIndex, startIndex) = 1
End Sub
```

Also I have to access it like, how would I do that with List(Of List(Of Byte)

```
If adjMatrix(index, j) = 1 Then
'Do stuff
End If
```

Comment: for using List, you will have to rewrite your logic. what is it that you are trying to achive?

Comment: I'm trying to work with a depth first search, code works great but I keep adding new Node connections and the adjMatrix has to be re-adjusted to support the new node endIndex.

Comment: Try using 2 1-dimensional arrays. In List traversal would be difficult.

Comment: `A List(Of List(Of Byte))` - do you understand the structure this would make. Every element is a `List(Of Byte)` each could have a diff number of element - a jagged array (old term)? Would a [Dictionary](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=vb.net%20dictionary&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fxfhwa508.aspx&ei=uaX0UeYZ5bLKAeb4gdAI&usg=AFQjCNHH5LI_I8tVxIuruYUtMpOWjilqsw&bvm=bv.49784469,d.aWc)(Of String, List(Of Byte)) be a better fit?

Comment: Not sure of the overhead cost, but it sounds like you could use a treeview class.  You could use it for the tree structure without showing it, but if you find a need to show it it's already organized for that.  Plus it's very dynamic, you can add, remove, change whatever you need.

Comment: these plain arrays are probably the least expensive and work best.. I was thinking maybe something like 1 dimensional array with `Redim perserve adjMatrix(node.count * nodeCount)` `(startIndex + (endIndex * nodes.Count))` and `(endIndex + startIndex * nodeCount)` and `If adjMatrix(index + (j * nodes.Count)) = 1 Then`  but the results are wrong then  @Guanxi I'll try that